# what is the assurity for JVM to start run() method of Threads in a sequence

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

For this below program, the ans is --> print : printName , then wait for 5 seconds then print : printValue

But as far as I know that its up to JVM to pick a thread and start its run method. So why it cannot be (printvalue printname and then 5 sec pause).

**Note** : I understand the conept of synchornized method but how we are sure here that JVM will always pick the thread t1 as its first thread.

```
class B {
    public synchronized void printName() {
        try {
            System.out.println("printName");
            Thread.sleep(5 * 1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }

    public synchronized void printValue() {
        System.out.println("printValue");
    }
}

public class Test1 extends Thread {
    B b = new B();

    public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception {
        Test1 t = new Test1();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(t, "t1");
        Thread t2 = new Thread(t, "t2");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        if (Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("t1")) {
            b.printName();
        } else {
            b.printValue();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When asking for help, take the time to indent your code readably. PM 77-1 has done it for you this time, but he really shouldn't have had to. You've asked 31 previous questions and posted 3 answers; this should be happening before you click the big button. Look at the preview. Give it a read-over. *Then* post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context, the `synchronize` just means that they can't run at the same time, not that they have to run in order.  If you want them to run in order, then you don't want threads, or you want a more sophisticated queuing mechanism.

So, you are correct in that the it could either be "printName" pause "printValue" *or* "printValue" "printName" pause.

If you run the program multiple times, you'll likely see the first one more frequently. You will see the second output occasionally.  The skew is because there is a slight delay between the `start()` on thread 1 and `start()` on thread 2.

Comment: this is what my concern is. SO here the answer of question is wrong, Am I right? I saw this qsn online and not sure about its answer.

Comment: @user3610891 What is your concern? The answer is correct, there is no specified/guranteed sequence.

Answer (score 0):

> how we are sure here that JVM will always pick the thread t1 as its first thread.

You can *never* be sure that the `t1` thread will start running before the `t2` thread starts running.  If you need the t1 thread to do something before the t2 thread does some other thing, then you will have to use some synchronization object (e.g., a `Semaphore`) to make `t2` wait.

```
Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(0);

Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        doTheThingThatHasToBeDoneFirst();
        semaphore.release();
        doOtherStuff();
    }
}).start();

Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        semaphore.acquire();  //will not return until t1 thread calls release().
        doOtherOtherStuff();
    }
}).start();
```

But that is not really a smart way to use threads.  Why not just do this instead?

```
doTheThingThatHasToBeDoneFirst();

Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        doOtherStuff();
    }
}).start();

Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        doOtherOtherStuff();
    }
}).start();
```

As a rule of thumb, the more synchronization you have between your threads, the less benefit you get from using threads.  If you want certain things to happen in a certain order, you should do those things in that order in a single thread.

The trick to using threads is to design your program so that there are useful things it can do where order does *not* matter.